# Link1104 error when Compiling a Project using clang in visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, llvm, clang

I want to parse C++ code in visual studio and do some data obfuscation and control obfuscation on C++ code.
I followed all the instructions in 'http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html'. and I built 'All_BUILD' project Successfully. I downloaded 'https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/commit/713f29c35620a730410588fd5bf4971c995e5a7d' project to learn how to use clang and work with AST. but when I was building 'tutorial1' project, I faced with 'error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clangIndex.lib' C:\Clang-tutorial-master\Clang-tutorial-master\Win\tutorial1\LINK.. I searched for clangIndex.lib in builded clang project but I found nothing.. any suggestion?
How can I build the project?
I'm using revision '180169' and 'visual studio 2010'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched clang repositories and understood that 'ClangIndex' project was in some older revisions of clang. but there is no ClangIndex project in current revision any more.
so I downloaded revision 75435 and built the project. now It's working..